# Mechanism of DNA gyrase inhibitor

Tags: biochemistry, dna, enzymes

Why DNA gyrase inhibitor, such as Nalidixic acid and Norfloxacin, do not stop gyrase from cutting DNA helix but only prevent them from decatenation replicating DNA?

Comment: Crysallographic studies do not exist for this yet. It has been predicted by computational methods that quinolones bind to DNA-gyrase complex and stall the enzyme at that step.

Comment: @WYSIWYG you should make that an answer

Comment: I didn't really answer the question.. If no better answer comes up then I'll find details and post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good article to read: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24497635

Robert Kerns's lab has been doing a lot of work on fluoroquinolines, so look into his other work as an entry to the literature. And apparently X-ray crystals have been done for at least parts of this complex. There is some evidence for fluoroquinolines binding to DNA, then moving into the protein as it moves along the DNA.